# How to get the hyperlink in a webpage written in JavaScript using a WebBrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, html, hyperlink, webbrowser-control

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(myurl); 
HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
MessageBox.Show(link.InnerHtml);         
}
```

I used the code above and can get the whole HTML document of the webpage, but what I really want is to get the hyperlink url(the url as ("a href")) in the HTML document.

I use:

```
MessageBox.Show(link.GetAttribute("href"));
```

but it returns null.

Could someone help me out of the problem **not using regular expressions** but using something like simple function?

The HTML code with JavaScript is shown as follows:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test for me</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--


function window::onload()
{

 result.innerHTML = 
      "<br><center><font size=+1><a href='MyMain.aspx' target='_parent'>Back to My Main        Page</a></font><br>"
    + "<font size=+2><b><a href='http://MySub.asp'>Launch My Application</a></b></font></center>";     
}

-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div id="result" />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is the window load function really `function window::onload()`?  That's not javascript... I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost a complete guess, but:

- You're likely going to have to wait until the document *actually
  loads* before you grab your content.
- You need to grab the right
  content ("A" tags)

Going by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx, I'd guess the following code might work:

First, set up an event handler:

```
// Add an event handler that processes the document after it loads.
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=
    new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(ProcessDocument);
```

elsewhere, define the handler (and what needs to happen)

```
private void ProcessDocument(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    var webBrowser1 = (WebBrowser)sender;

    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(link.GetAttribute("href"));         
    }

}
```

and finally:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(myurl);
```

The problem is, the msdn documentation doesn't say much as to what has to happen before a document is "completely loaded".

Edit:  I finally tried it in LinqPad, and It doesn't look like it exposes anything relating to the "window load" event, at least directly.  I would wager the DocumentCompleted event is fired more like a "DOMReady" event.  The following is a bit of a hack, but it appears on the third invocation of the DocumentTitleChange event, it grabs the contents of the href.  PLEASE NOTE the reason why it's invoked the third time is that *I have javascript that changes the title*!

```
void Main()
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser1.DocumentTitleChanged +=
        new EventHandler(ProcessDocument);
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost/test/test.html"); 

    Console.ReadLine();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

private void ProcessDocument(object sender,
    EventArgs e)
{

    var webBrowser1 = (WebBrowser)sender;
    Console.WriteLine("ProcessDocument BEGIN");
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(link.GetAttribute("href"));         
    }
    Console.WriteLine("ProcessDocument END");
    Console.Out.Flush();

}
```

Where your html is:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test for me</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--


function foo()
{
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
 result.innerHTML = 
      "<br><center><font size=+1><a href='MyMain.aspx' target='_parent'>Back to My Main        Page</a></font><br>"
    + "<font size=+2><b><a href='http://MySub.asp'>Launch My Application</a></b></font></center>";
  document.title += "Hack..Aacklgahala, ribbit";    
}

-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY onload="foo()">
<a href="http://google.com">bar</a>
<div id="result" />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, JayC. I will try your method. :)